# Improper data returned by reference.on('value') in firebase web api

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using firebase realtime database Node API (import "firebase-admin"), improper values (empty updates) are randomly delivered via `query.on('value')` as the initial update.

I rely proper data being delivered from the very first update. The reason why I'm using .on('value') is code reuse, in other places that require the data stream.

1. What is the contract on the data updates in firebase?
2. If I switch to `.once('value')` does it change the contract?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understand what you're doing, and what the problem is. Can you update your question with a single snippet of code that reproduces the problem you're asking about? See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There is no reproduction scenario I can provide, as the error occurs randomly. Data returned by ```.ref().child('res').orderByChild("t").startAt.on('value', cb)``` callback sometimes returns an empty snapshot instead of the data the node contains. My question: What are the guaranties on the data returned by firebase via ```.on('value', cb)``` function? Does switching to ```.once('value',cb)``` assure the data is re-loaded?

Comment: I've never seen Firebase return data randomly, so I doubt that is happening here. So if you have a problem that seems like that, isolate it in your code and share that code. That's the only way we can reason about what is happening in your environment.